# XSLT Select all 3rd level children of current node by name

Tags: xml, xslt, child-nodes

I am trying to use apply-templates to iterate over a particular child node from multiple similar parent nodes. Example below:

```
<test_report 
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<countries>
    <country name='sample1'>
        <education>
            <men>
                <literacyRates>25,36,43</literacyRates>
            </men>
        </education>
    </country>
    <country name='sample2'>
        <education>
            <men>
                <literacyRates>45,46,55,56</literacyRates>
            </men>
        </education>
    </country>
</countries>
```

Now, I want to apply a template on all the literacyRates element that falls under the countries element. I tried the below XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="countries">
            <xsl:call-template name="countries" />   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="countries" match="literacyRate">
        <xsl:call-template name="testoutput"><xsl:with-param name="list" select="." /> </xsl:call-template>
    ]
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="testoutput">
        <xsl:param name="list" select="."/>
    list=<xsl:value-of select="$list" />
</xsl:template>
```

I would have expected the output line starting with `list=` to have appeared twice since we have two matches for literacyRate element, but that is not the case. Need some help here.

Comment: What do you need all those `xsl:call-template` for if your aim is to `apply-templates`? The `match="countries"` is fine to match `countries` elements, then, to apply-templates to the `literacyRates` descendants simply use `<xsl:apply-templates select=".//literacyRates"/>` and inside a matching template for those elements then output what you need to output.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following script:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="country//literacyRates">
    <xsl:text>list=</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or another solution, if you **realy** need to use `apply-templates`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="countries">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//literacyRates"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="literacyRates">
    <xsl:text>list=</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

### The existing XSL code

Your XSL has a number of problems.

- You use `call-template` in ways that don't make much sense.  Using `apply-templates` would be more idiomatic.
- You have three templates, but you only actually do anything in the last one -- and that one only outputs the string value of the `<countries>` element.  May as well have just one template:

  ```
  <xsl:template match="countries">
      list=<xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  ```

  (I assume here that the newline and `]` closing bracket in your second template is a typo.)
- Your second template has both a `name` attribute and a `match` attribute.

  ```
  <xsl:template name="countries" match="literacyRate">
        <xsl:call-template name="testoutput"><xsl:with-param name="list" select="." /> </xsl:call-template>
      ]
  </xsl:template>
  ```

  The `match` attribute only does anything if you are using `apply-templates` earlier in the processing flow.  Since you only ever use `call-template` instead, the `match` attribute does nothing.
  Moreover, since the `match` attribute specifies `literacyRate`, but your input XML only has `literacyRates` elements, this *still* wouldn't do anything, even if you used `apply-templates` earlier.

### A working approach: text output

It looks like you want to have one `list=` line for each individual `<country>` element.  To generate this output as straight text, the following works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="countries">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="country//literacyRates"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="literacyRates">
        <xsl:text>list=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Breaking this down, we have:

- `<xsl:output method="text"/>` to specify that we are outputting text, not XML.  This may affect the output formatting, depending on your XSL processor.
- `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to prevent whitespace (i.e. indentation) in the source XML and XSL from affecting whitespace in the output.
- `<xsl:apply-templates select="country//literacyRates"/>` to `apply-templates`, and to specifically `select` only those `literacyRates` elements that are descendants of a `country` element.

#### Assumptions

This assumes that each `<country>` element has **only one** `<literacyRates>` descendant element.  If there are multiple such elements, the output will get messy -- each list of values will be appended to the output string, potentially resulting in output lines like `list=25,36,4345,46,55,56` (where two lists are munged together, with nothing in between).

### A working approach: XML output

The text output above is somewhat lossy and confusing -- we have no idea which list belongs to which country, and multiple `<literacyRates>` in one `<country>` will produce broken output.

Here's an alternative output that generates XML, with more information included.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="countries">
        <SampleOutput>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="country//literacyRates"/>
        </SampleOutput>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="literacyRates">
        <literacyRates>
            <xsl:attribute name="country" select="ancestor::country/@name"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="type" select="name(..)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </literacyRates>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```